# How do I prove that $ f(n) = (n + 1)! - 1 $ is an injective function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

I have this problem:

> Consider the function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by
>
> $$f(n) = (n+1)! - 1$$
>
> Prove that $f$ is injective.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way probably to prove this is by proving that $f$ is strictly increasing. You can do that quite easily using induction.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $f(n)=f(m)$.  Then $(n+1)!-1=(m+1)!-1$.  Adding $1$ to each side we conclude that $(n+1)!=(m+1)!$.  We assume without loss of generality, by swapping the names of $m,n$ if necessary, that $n\ge m$.  We now divide both sides by $(m+1)!$ to conclude $$1=\frac{(n+1)!}{(m+1)!}=\frac{(m+1)!(m+2)(m+3)\cdots(n+1)}{(m+1)!}=(m+2)(m+3)\cdots (n+1)$$

If there is even one term on the right, that term is $n+1>1$, which  is a contradiction.  Hence there are no terms on the right, i.e. $n=m$.